# How to get the Logger messages displayed in IDE from Java to Vue front-end

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, slf4j

Issue:

I would like to know how can I get the Logger messages displayed in Java IDE to front-end web applications so users can know the various Logger messages.

Background:

I am developing a web application using `Vuejs` as front-end and `Java` as a backend service. I have a `textarea` where users can provide `XML` data. This data are sent to the `Java` backend where it will be validated against `XSD Schema` and various other things and appropriate `LOG` messages are added using the `Slf4j Log`. Also, some data are returned by the `Java Backend Service`.

I am able to get the `returned Data` and `Exception` from my `Java` within the `VUEJS` call but the `Log` messages are displayed only in my `Java IDE IntelliJ` and I am not understanding how to get these data as well in the `VUEJS` call.

I would like to display the `Log` messages as well to the user so that they can get an understanding of what's happening in the backend.

I tried searching a lot but could not get an idea on whether its possible or if possible how. Can someone please guide me on this?

Following is the code sample using `VuejS` and `Springboot` which makes call to my `Java Backend Service`:

```
<textarea class="form-control" v-model="xmlEvents" ref="xmlEvents" @input="convertToJSON()" placeholder="XML Data"></textarea>
```

My call to Spring boot:

```
methods: {
    convertToJSON() {
        ConverterService.convertToJson(this.xmlEvents)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
              this.jsonEvents = JSON.stringify(response.data, undefined, "\t");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.jsonEvents = error.response.data.detail;
          });
    } 
}
```

My service:

```
import http from "../http-common";

class ConverterService {
  //Method to convert the XML events to JSON
  convertToJson(data) {
    return http.post("/jsonConverter", data);
  }
}

export default new ConverterService();
```

My spring boot application:

```
    @PostMapping("/jsonConverter")
    public String convertToJson(@RequestBody String xmlEvents) throws ConverterException {
        try {
            final InputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlEvents.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            final ByteArrayOutputStream jsonOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new XmlToJsonConverter().convert(xmlStream);
            return new String(jsonOutput.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

All I would like to know is how to get the `Log` messages which are being displayed within the `Console` of my `IntelliJ IDE` within my `VueJS` call along with the response that is sent for the request call.

Comment: users don't use an IDE. Users also shouldn't be aware of the logging, the maintainer of the application should be.

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for the response. I agree but the `Log` messages added within the `Java` application are relevant to the user so I would like to get them and show them in the front-end. The log messages are related to whether the XML adheres to schema invalid entries etc. For these it's not necessary to throw exceptions so we are making use of log messages. I would like to show this in the front-end so users are aware of it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not handle exceptions and render user-friendly error messages to your client? logs are not meant to be shared with clients/users.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 showing them in the front-end is very different compared to showing them in the console of the/an IDE

Comment: @Mo_- Thanks for the response. Actually, these are not `Exceptions` rather a `Warning`. I have a lot `Exceptions` in the code and I am able to access and show them using the `Exception Handling approach` but I would also like to show the user `Warnings` that may have occurred during the execution. These `Warnings` are show in `Java IDE` as `Log Messages` so I would also like to access these `Log Messages` during my `Java Backend call` and show them to user.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I agree. So does that mean it's not possible to display the `Java IDE` Log messages within the client-side browser?

Comment: of course that is possible. send it as text, and a simple setText will do

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for the guidance. Do you have some sort of sample documentation or code sample that I can refer to. I am unable to find anything similar. Any example or links would be really helpful.

Comment: just to implement a setText?

Comment: @Stultuske If you observe my `SpringBoot` code from the question I am returning `String` directly to my `front-end`, where to use `setText` on that. Also, how can I access the `log` messages within the code and use the `setText` to add the values. I am a bit confused and not exactly following what you mean by `setText` as I am bit new to `SpringBoot`. Hence, I was asking for an example where they may have done this.

Comment: this is not related to springboot, but to the logging. whereever you have "log.info(...)" or similar, keep this in a String, and return that to the front-end, or a value based on it. or, the exception you encounter, in the front-end, put the text or the message of the exception in a text field

Comment: @Stultuske The problem is that `Log.info` messages are not added by me within my `SpringBoot` application. These `Logging` messages are coming from another `Java Service` which is called by my `SpringBoot` application. So I am not sure when and where these `Log messages` will come up so I cannot store them into the `String` as you are mentioning. I need an approach where I can Catch all the `Logs` within my `Spring Boot` that has been logged by another `Java Service`. I hope I was able to explain you the problem I am facing.

Comment: you can't provide the user with data you have no access to

Comment: @Stultuske I believe you are not understanding what I am trying to explain. 1. I have a `VueJS` app that is making a call to my `SpringBoot` application. 2. My `VueJS` is running on `Port 3000` and I have started my `SpringBoot` application on `Port 9000` using my `IntelliJ IDE`. 3. My `SpringBoot` application is making a call to another 3rd party`Java Service` which I have included in my `Pom.xml`. 4. When I make a call to my `SpringBoot` application from `VueJS` it internally makes a call to 3rd party `Java Service`. 5. During this execution some messages are logged by 3rd party Java service

Comment: @Stultuske `6.` I am able to see these `Log messages` from 3rd party `Java API` within my `Intellij IDE Run Window` as my `SpringBoot` application is running there. `7.` All I would like to know is how to capture these `Log` messages which are provided by 3rd party `Java API` and send it to the front-end. I am getting them on the `IntelliJ IDE` through the `Java Service`. I would like to send them to `VueJS`.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. but just because I can see the sun, doesn't mean I can throw a bucket of water over it.